# Is there any way to find documents with similar titles using FullTextSqlQuery?

Tags: search, object-model, fulltextsqlquery

Say I have a document with the title, `Calendar events for December` and another document with the title `Month of December Calendar of Events`.

Is there some way to determine that these are very similar using a [FullTextSqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.fulltextsqlquery.aspx)?  If not, is there something else provided in the object model that would work for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *FREETEXT* predicate in FullTextSqlQuery.*FREETEXT* matches the meanings of phrases against fields.

Comment: Very cool, I will give this a shot.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think FullTextQuery supports distinct. You best bet would be to fetch the results using a combination of LINQ and FullTextQuery.

Following thread will give you a quick snapshot of how it can be done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469960/distinct-department-names-sharepoint-search

Comment: I don't see what selecting distinct records has to do with my question.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I thought you meant distinct titles. I guess it may be tough without full blown search products.